# How to integrate R with PHP?

Tags: php, r

im new to PHP and i want to run Rscript inside PHP.I tried the method mentioned here http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/, but it dint work. Im using wamp server in windows.The forms loads but once the input $N is entered,the Rscript fails to run.(This i found out by seeing whether image is created).The location of my php and r script is in "c:\wamp\www\".So,do i have to set the path of exec function to Rscript.exe location??or is there any other way??Please help..

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
// poorman.php

echo "<form action='poorman.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
$N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N");

  // return image tag
  $nocache = rand();
  echo("<img src='temp.png?$nocache' />");
 }
?>
```

This is the r script

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

N <- args[1]
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the result of exec(). E.g. via

```
exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N 2>&1", $output);
echo '<pre>', join("\r\n", $output), "</pre>\r\n";
```

exec() only returns the output sent to stderr: 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout (works under windows as well), so you should also see error messages like e.g."RScript: command not found"